# Customised MultiResourceItemReader: assign different mappers/writers for each file inside an archive

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement to read/process an archive which contains several flat files, each file should have it's own mapping and writer.

How do I go about assigning different `FieldSetmappers` and Writers for each file
using the bean configuration.

I have started with extending the `MultiResourceItemReader` and overriding the **`open`** method
as shown here:

```java
    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
            throws ItemStreamException {

        ZipFile zipFile;
        List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
        try {
            zipFile = new ZipFile(pathtozipfile);
            Enumeration zippedFile = zipFile.entries();
            while (zippedFile.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) zippedFile.nextElement();
                resources.add(new InputStreamResource(zipFile
                        .getInputStream(zipEntry), zipEntry.getName()));

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.setResources(resources.toArray(new Resource[resources.size()]));

        super.open(executionContext);
    }
```

and the bean declaration as follows:

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="com.proc.spring.ZipMResourceItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="pathtozipfile" value="#{jobParameters['input.pathtozipfile']}" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="delegateReader" />   </bean>

 <bean id="delegateReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="lineMapper1">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.." />
        </property>
   </bean>
```

I know programmatically, I could use the `getCurrentResource()` during read but I expect spring must support the ability to assign different `FieldSetMappers` based on current resource of the `MultiResourceItemReader`.

I guess perhaps extracting the files as the first step then assign each file/resource to a step: `FlatFileItemReader` would be solution  but would prefer to use delegate method if its possible to differentiate the mappers/writers based on the resource name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: extract all files in a previous step is the best pratice.

A solution can involve a custom [`ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream.html) used to dispatch to correct reader looking at current resource name; you can do dispatch manually or using a `Classifier`. This custom reader is used as delegate of your multiresource item reader.

```
class ReaderDispatcher implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<Object> {
  private ItemReader<Object> delegate1;
  private ItemReader<Object> delegate2;
  private ItemReader<Object> delegate1;
  private ItemReader<Object> currentDelegate;
  private Resource resource;

  public setResource(org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
    currentDelegate = getDelegateFromResource();
  }
  public Object read() {
    return currentDelegate.read();
  }
  // Others interfaces implementation (or extends from one of abstract reader/stream implementations)
  private ItemReader getDelegateFromResource() {
    // here code to detect right reader from delegateN
  }
}
```

(sorry for untested/incomplete code; I am unable to check it, but I hope you can see the idea behind).
You can pre-configure your readers with its own fieldSetMapper or any other customization you want.
Check [`ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream.html) for writer counterpart of reader interface.

Comment: thanks!! Luca, I agree that extracting all files as the first step is best practice! i have already implemented a prototype but it's always nice to have other solutions to compare against...., so this will coming handy.